# Using USB in my app

Tags: android

I wanna use USB in my app, when I put Flash Memory in my pc I want to transfer data from Flash Memory to my app.

Do you have any idea about this feature and is this already supported?

Comment: You want to plug a usb flash driver into your PC and have an android device do something?  That's going to be quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the new [Android Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html).  The only issue is that it will only work with Android versions >= 2.3.3.

Comment: The protocol might help, the offered hardware probably not.  But there's probably not anything the ADK protocol can do which the ADB protocol could not be used to accomplish on earlier devices if the owner is comfortable to enable USB debugging.

Comment: It allows you to attach your app to a piece of software acting as a USB host.  So, I think, you could write a piece of software for the computer that listens for your app to connect and initiates the data transfer.

Comment: It will be interesting if the ADK protocol ends up being use more as the previously missing "sync" protocol than for hardware devices.  Though perhaps there are also possibilities in the MTP replacement for USB mass strage.